# Java code to remove initial lines of a file executing very slow

Tags: java, bufferedreader, filereader

I have written java code to remove initial characters from a file with 200k records , the file is removing the initial characters but its reading the file line by line and removing the characters .The program is executing very slow . Any tweaks could be made to below code to execute it faster ?

The program is executing and writing the output to a file , but its very slow

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class truncate {
    public static void main(String [] args) {

        // The name of the file to open.
        String inputfile = "C:\\Program Files\\eclipse\\twfiles.txt";
        String outputfile = "C:\\Program Files\\eclipse\\rename.txt";

        // This will reference one line at a time
        String line = "";
        int number_of_char_to_erased =19;

        try {
            // FileReader reads text files in the default encoding.
            FileReader fileReader = 
                new FileReader(inputfile);

            // Always wrap FileReader in BufferedReader.
            BufferedReader bufferedReader = 
                new BufferedReader(fileReader);

            while((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println(line);

                File input = new File(inputfile);
                Scanner scan = new Scanner(input);
                File output = new File(outputfile);
                PrintStream print = new PrintStream(output);

                while (scan.hasNext()) {
                 line = scan.nextLine();
                 line = line.substring(number_of_char_to_erased);
                 print.println(line);
                }

                scan.close();
                print.close();
            }   

            // Always close files.
            bufferedReader.close();         
        }
        catch(FileNotFoundException ex) {
            System.out.println(
                "Unable to open file '" + 
                        inputfile + "'");               
        }
        catch(IOException ex) {
            System.out.println(
                "Error reading file '" 
                + inputfile + "'");                 
            // Or we could just do this: 
            // ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't understand the point of the Scanner. Why not simply write the line.substring into your output file?

Comment: Did you try removing System.out.println(line) from the while loop ?  Printing 200k lines to console is a heavy task.

Answer (score 1):

What appears to be the issue here is that you just created a buffered reader to read the file. Then, it reads the first line of the file. Then, you create a Scanner to read ALL the lines in the file, omitting certain characters. Then your BufferedReader reads the next line in the file. And the process repeats itself. So all you have to do is this:

```
  File output = new File(outputfile);
  PrintStream print = new PrintStream(output);   

  while((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {

            print.println(line.substring(number_of_char_to_erased);

   }
   print.close();
```

This should much faster. Basically, since you've already allocated line to the read line from the file, you can simply print out that line, minus the number of chars, to the output file. The entire for loop with scanner was entirely unnecessary, and closing and opening the print stream for each line was also unnecessary.

EDIT: Removed the println statement since it would slow it down a bit.

Comment: Thanks Elven . Your edited code works fast and it takes less than a second. I have edited the code suggested by you and works superb. Thanks a ton.

Answer (score 0):

Try this (Scanner and Println removed, output file refactored outside the loop):

```
import java.io.*;

public class truncate {
public static void main(String [] args) {

    // The name of the file to open.
    String inputfile = "C:\\Program Files\\eclipse\\twfiles.txt";
    String outputfile = "C:\\Program Files\\eclipse\\rename.txt";

    // This will reference one line at a time
    String line = "";
    int number_of_char_to_erased =19;

    try {
        // FileReader reads text files in the default encoding.
        FileReader fileReader = new FileReader(inputfile);

        // Always wrap FileReader in BufferedReader.
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(fileReader);

        File output = new File(outputfile);
        PrintStream print = new PrintStream(output);

        while((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {

             String trimmedLine = line.substring(number_of_char_to_erased);
             print.println(trimmedLine);


        }   

        // Always close files.
        bufferedReader.close();
        print.close();        
    }
    catch(FileNotFoundException ex) {
        System.out.println(
            "Unable to open file '" + 
                    inputfile + "'");               
    }
    catch(IOException ex) {
        System.out.println(
            "Error reading file '" 
            + inputfile + "'");                 
        // Or we could just do this: 
        // ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Hi Matt , Thanks for edited code. Together with your code and Elvin code , now the program executes very fast. Thanks for lighting response. Cheers.